# unable to test regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm pretty unfamiliar with RegExp, and Im trying to implement it to detect urls in strings. The one regexp I want to use is this one (please don't provide your own):

```
/(((http|ftp|https)://)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;/~+#-])?)/g
```

And replace all the matches with this:

```
<a href="$1">$1</a>
```

If you visit http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ with that example and use it in the replace, you'll see it works flawlessly, but it's impossible to build a working solution with this in javascript.

```
var text = "hi, demo link http://stackoverflow.com is a great website"
//regexp magic


//expected result:
textWithLink ="hi, demo link <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">http://stackoverflow.com</a> is a great website"
```

Comment: How have you tried to express that regex in JS syntax? How have you tried to use the resulting regex object?

Comment: @Jack you have to escape the forward slashes within the regex

Comment: @JanDvorak Hmm, I assumed that wasn't necessary when you do `var re = new RegExp('(((http|ftp|https)://)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;/~+#-])?)', 'g');`

Comment: @Jack that's correct, but you normally create regexes as `/.../g`

Comment: @JanDvorak That's just an alternative writing style, I don't think that should really matter, except for the fact that you have to escape the forward slash when the delimiter is already that.

Comment: @Jack I mean, if you do use a literal, you have to escape forward slashes. If you use a RegExp constructor, you have to escape quotes instead. Also, I recommend using the literal where possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = 'hi, demo link http://stackoverflow.com is a great website',
    regex = /(((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?)/g;
str.replace(regex, '<a href="$1">$1</a>');
```

Note: It's your exact regex, I just escaped the forward slashes.

Comment: Thanks to all, I now understand much better how to use regex in js.
Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
var ok = /(((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;/~+#-])?)/.test(str);
```

to test if a string is an URL.

If you want to look for URLs in a string, use

```
var matches = str.match(/(((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;/~+#-])?)/g);
```

Note that it's a [regex literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and that I had to escape the `/`.

Comment: @JanDvorak I already answered my own question, I'll delete my comments.

Answer (score 1):

The RegExp literal you provide is invalid:

```
/(((http|ftp|https)://)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;/~+#-])?)/g
^                   ^^
Start               |\__ Error
                    |
                   End
```

It works in the link you provide because that application strips delimiters automatically and inadvertently fixes the error.